# react native - Failed to set an indexed property on 'CSSStyleDeclaration'

Tags: react-native

I want to dynamically substitute the css variable but get the below error -

global.js

```
answerzerocontainer: {
        flex: .5,
        backgroundColor: '#fcba03',
        marginBottom:10,
        justifyContent: 'center',        
    },
```

test.js

```
<View style={globalStyles.homepagecontainer}>
            <Text>{question}</Text>            
            {
                answers.map((a, key)=> {
                    key = 'zero'
                    const cssstyle = 'globalStyles.answer' + key + 'container'
                    console.log('style - ', cssstyle)
                    return (<View style={cssstyle}>
                                <Text>a</Text>
                            </View>)
                })
            }
```

error :-

```
Failed to set an indexed property on 'CSSStyleDeclaration'
```

Comment: I recommend you to use the state of the app for that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the number values also inside a pair of single quotes '10'.